# How do I get the name of the file being executed in a perldb-mode-hook?

Tags: gdb, gud, perl

I've been adding some modifications to the perldb which goes through gud.  When started it calls its `perldb-mode-hook` so that and `.perldb` is where I'm working.

From within the hook I can get the buffer name which is in the form `*gud-`*script.pl*`*` and thus in the context of the gud comint buffer where there is no file being visited.  I could parse the file's name out of the buffer name, but it seems I should be able to get the path and name of the Perl file executed or the whole command line run.

Answer (score 0):

No one else has answered my question so I just went ahead and did this:

```
;; Alt regex to remove file ext "^\\*?\\(gud-\\)?\\(.+?\\)\\(\\.pl\\)*\\*?$"
(setq term-file-name
        (replace-regexp-in-string
             "^\\*?\\(gud-\\)?\\(.+?\\)\\*?$" "\\1term-\\2" (buffer-name)
(message "Using %s as term buffer, script and pipe name." term-file-name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information you want by looking at the variable `gud-perldb-history`.  Every time you run <kbd>M-x perldb</kbd>, the full command line used to run the Perl Debugger will be prepended to the front of that list.

```lisp
;; Get the most recent command run under perldb.
(car gud-perldb-history)

;; Get just the command line without the "perl -d ".
(replace-regexp-in-string
 (concat "^" gud-perldb-command-name " ") ; debugger command
 ""                                       ; removed
 (car gud-perldb-history))                ; leaving the command line

;; Get the full path to the script.
(nth 2 (split-string-and-unquote (car gud-perldb-history)))
```

The last one is a bit fragile, because it assumes the presence of "perl -d" and skips over the first two strings to get at the script path.  This should be a good starting point for whatever you're trying to do though.